# How to enable National Geographic images (Megaflyover) in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

In Google maps there are overlay photos shot from plane ([Megaflyover project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MegaFlyover)).

There are various instructions how to watch this, like http://googlesightseeing.com/2007/03/national-geographic-african-megaflyover-project/

> load up Google Earth and switch on the “National Geographic Magazine
>   Layer” under Featured Content

or like http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~globalconn/ng.html

> Turn on the National Geographic layer under the Featured Content
>   section.

But all I see (the most similar to it) is "DigitalGlobe Featured Imagery" which is apparently something else.

Perhaps the way how NG layer is now in GE has changed in the meantime? How to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it - it is under "Gallery" now:

[image]